# Node.js: how to create relative links to website endpoints from the server side

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node and am having difficulty defining a relative address for a site endpoint from the server-side.

**What I want to do**

I'm using passport-local for session auth in Express. When the user creates a new account, I'd like to:

1. Create the new account in the DB
2. Retrieve the new user account from the DB, including its db-generated user ID
3. Log the user in with that info.

I've got all this working except 3. I haven't yet figured out how to take an object in Node and POST it to a relative endpoint. On my local setup, for example, I'd like to POST the returned user object to localhost:3000/login.

Axios handles the POST request fine, except when I provide "/login" as the URL, it targets the path "/mycomputer/myapp/routers/login".

**Some things I've Tried**

```
router.post("/user/create", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    }
    createUser(newUser, (err, returnedUserObject) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      axios.post("/login", returnedUserObject)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    });
})
```

I've also tried:

```
...
  createUser(newUser, (err, returnedUserObject) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      axios.post(path.join(__dirname, "/login"), returnedUserObject)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    });
})
```

Both interpret the path relative to the file system. :/

I've also tried initiating the POST request from within `createUser()` but I get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What's the `login` function for? Is it to show a homepage? Or is it to create an authentication token?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in my projects to configure axios base route is to create an axios instance and then use it for future requests. You can make a util file like this named axiosInstance:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'localhost:3000'
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

Then wherever you need to make axios requests, import that file and do the HTTP method on the axiosInstance, like this in your example:

```
import axiosInstance from 'your_path';

router.post("/user/create", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password
    }
    createUser(newUser, (err, returnedUserObject) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      axiosInstance.post("/login", returnedUserObject)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    });
})
```